# how to access odoo remotely on network?

Tags: server, odoo, remote-server, odoo-10, erp

I have install Odoo on windows server 2008 with fixed ip and this machine connect with Ethernet in network.And my ip address is 192.168.1.200.
So how to access Odoo remotely in network.

Comment: Do you get any errors when you try and access 192.168.1.200:8069?

Answer (score 2):

By default odoo runs on port 8069. So try *192.168.1.200:8069.*

Or if you have defined any other port in your conf file, then change 8069 to that port.

Also you can check log file(if you have specified), It will show like *running on 0.0.0.0:port_number.*